# Conflicting dependencies in Androidstudio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

How can I solve this problem?
[image]

It seems that different versions of android support and firebase are troublesome. But I didn't write the dependencies: there were there once I created the project and linked it to firebase.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification)

Comment: If you put the cursor on the underlined text, and press ctrl-return, it will make a suggestion as to what the correct version should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change these two dependencies to the versions shown:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:3.0.0'
```

In future questions, please post text instead of an image. That allows the text to be copied, used for evaluation and answering.

There are three version numbers that must be made consistent:

1. Firebase and Google Play libraries
2. Android Support libraries
3. FirebaseUI

The [FirebaseUI documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries) contains a table of compatible Firebase SDK versions.  To determine the needed Support library version, you need to run a Gradle task to see the dependencies, or deduce the version by looking at the warnings Android Studio reports with red underlines on the dependencies in the app build.gradle file.

The latest version of Firebase is listed in the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android).  To keep this answer simple, I used 11.4.2.  The latest is 11.6.2, but IIRC would require more extensive changes to your build setup for repos and classpaths.

Comment: Worked liked a charm! Thank you very much. How did you know which version numbers I should compile?